# create a public survey in Office 365

Tags: 2013, office-365

I want to create a survey in office 365 where anyone can go and submit a response and there should be no need to login

Is there a way to achieve this?

I am also ok to create a public facing page, and use CSOM to submit response to list

Can someone please suggest a possible solution for achieving this

Answer (score 5):

It basically depends on what kind of site you created under Office 365.

Office 365 only allows anonymous access when creating a "Public Facing Site" template

Any other templates, like "Team Sites" do no support anonymous access.

In the survey settings, you need to set the anonymous access to make to public.

Comment: the problem I have with public facing site is that they are not supported anymore

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use Microsoft Forms, this is something new that has been recently introduced. It has an option to allow anon users to respond

**STEP 1**: Create survey

[image: survey]

**STEP 2** :Share the survey link through mail or you can also embed it where ever you want. Anyone with this link can respond to the survey

[image: survey output]

Comment: yeah i thought of that first, but I want to make some css style changes as per the requirement which doesn't seem possible in forms :(